Modulating with 64-QAM modulation
I'm new to this community. I'm trying to make a sender receiver device with using 64-QAM modulation. But I don't know how to code it or making the waveform. I am trying to make it on Altera Cyclone IV FPGA module. Is this possible or should I use another modulation or device? Also I'm trying to simulate it on Matlab waveform generator but I didn't understand much from that parameters.

Hi Maria- I think your question is much too broad for this site. What you are undertaking is a significant development beyond what can be answered in a few paragraphs and would require a back and forth discussion to productively proceed. Please do post more focused questions as you proceed with your interesting project.

I’m voting to close this question because it’s much too broad to be answered productively

1.-
With MATLAB sure you can program your Altera FPGA.
You need to combine Altera's DSP Builder with MATLAB Toolbox HDL Coder.
2.-
Read this Article : Using Altera DSP Builder Advanced Blockset with HDL Coder available here :
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/hdlcoder/ug/using-altera-dsp-builder-advanced-blockset-with-hdl-coder.html
3.-
More HDL Coder examples available in this page :
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/hdlcoder/examples.html?s_tid=CRUX_topnav
4.-
And this is HDL Coder Introductory page
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/hdlcoder/index.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav
QUOTE :
" ..
*HDL Coder enables high-level design for FPGAs, SoCs, and ASICs by generating portable, synthesizable Verilog, SystemVerilog, and VHDL code from MATLAB functions, Simulink models, and Stateflow® charts. You can use the generated HDL code for FPGA programming, ASIC prototyping, and production design.
HDL Coder includes a workflow advisor that automates prototyping generated code on Xilinx, Intel, and Microchip boards and generates IP cores for ASIC and FPGA workflows.
You can optimize for speed and area, highlight critical paths, and generate resource utilization estimates before synthesis.
HDL Coder provides traceability between SIMULINK models and the generated Verilog, SystemVerilog, and VHDL code, enabling code verification for high-integrity applications adhering to DO-254 and other standards
.."

END OF QUOTE
